# PHP: replace 3 characters every 4th character in string

Tags: php, string, replace, intervals

I have a string and I want to know how can I keep 1 character in a 4 character interval.

```
$string = "bc7yad3odf0x"; // and goes like this..
```

I want my new string to be:

```
yox
```

which comes out of <strike>bc7</strike> y <strike>ad3</strike> o <strike>df0</strike> x

The three characters to be ommited are always like char-char-number.

EDIT: Thank you all for answering. I tested all your answers and they work fine for me, except trisweb's preg_replace() solution, where I get "Unknown modifier 'g'".
I accept Bhavik Shah's answer since I think is the simplest to my understanding.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/) See [ask advice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice), please.

Comment: http://php.net/substr?

Comment: Is the original string always going to be the same length?

Comment: @John Conde I have tried preg_replace() but I only managed to keep the first character and ommit the next three. I couldn't think of a way how to make it the other way around.

Comment: @Quentin Engles No, the length of the original string is almost never the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$nstr = "";
$str_array = array();

//split string in chunks of 4-char strings
$str_array = str_split($string, 4);

//loop through all elements of array and take the required character
foreach($str_array as $key => $value){
    $nstr .= $value[3];
}
echo $nstr;
```

More details about [**str_split**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php).

Answer (score 4):

Just it

```
preg_replace("/\w{3}(\w)/","$1",$string);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$str = "bc7yad3odf0x";
$final_str = "";
$len = strlen($str);

for($i = 3; $i < $len; $i = $i+4) {
    $final_str .= substr($str, $i, 1)." ";
}

echo $final_str;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$newString = implode(
    '',
    array_map(
        function($value) {
            return substr($value,-1);
        },
        str_split($string,4)
    )
);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$string = "bc7yad3odf0x";
$new_string = "";
$iterations = ceil(strlen($string)/4);

for ($i=1;$i <= $iterations; $i++)
{
    $new_string .= substr($string, $i*4-1, 1);
}

print $new_string;
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a job for a regular expression!

```
$kept = preg_replace('/[a-z]{2}[0-9]/gi', "", $string);
```

What we're doing here is replacing occurrences of the kind "letter-letter-number" with a blank string, removing them.

If the string is always of the form you say, then it should work fine. However, if you always simply want the 4th character kept, you could use:

```
$kept = preg_replace('/.{3}(.)/gi', "$1", $string);
```

Or, to use a similar idea of using backreferences to make the first form more strict, use:

```
$kept = preg_replace('/[a-z]{2}[0-9](.)/gi', "$1", $string);
```

For more on using regular expressions in PHP, [see this nice article.](http://www.noupe.com/php/php-regular-expressions.html)

Answer (score 1):

in php you can access string like arrays

example:

```
$text = "abcde";
echo $text[1]; // b
```

so you could take every forth character and concatenate it to your final string. That is the easiest way i can think of at the moment.

Comment: Maybe you should put that in a loop with jumps of 4 and an example string the same length as the one in the question. Your solution is perfect as long as there aren't any other conditions than what's in the question right now. It may not need a loop if the length of string is always the same. I'll ask the questioner.

Answer (score 1):

Better use regex:

```
$var = "bc7yad3odf0x";

$var = preg_replace("/[a-z]{2}[0-9]([a-z])/i","$1",$var);

echo $var;

$var = "bc7yad3odf0x";

$var = preg_replace("/[a-z]{2}[0-9]/i","",$var);

echo $var;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$y = 3;
for($i=0; $i<strlen($string); $i++){
    if($y < strlen($string)){
        $out .= substr($string,$y,1);
        $y = $y+4;
    }else{
        break;
    }
}
echo $out;
```

Answer (score 1):

It's easy for-loop

```
$ans = "";
for($i = 3, $l = strlen($s); $i < $l; $i += 4)
    $ans .= $s[$i];
```